# Regular expression month validation with text-mask directive

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using [**text-mask**](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2#readme) angular2 directive with ionic2.I have a month JS regular expression like this `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/`.It is working fine.But now I need to apply this for above directive.I have tried like below.But it is not working.Can you tell me why?

```
   mask: Array<string | RegExp>;

   constructor(){
     this.mask = [/0[1-9]/, /1[0-2]/];//not working
     //this.mask = [/[1-9]/, /\d/]; //this is working
    }
```

Comment: Each element in the array imposes restriction on what char a user can input. It seems they are context-unaware. `[/0[1-9]/, /1[0-2]/]` means the first symbol can consist of `0` and a digit from `1` to `9` and the second symbol should start with `1` and then be followed with `0`, `1` or `2` - which is always false.

Comment: Why not just use `pattern="0[1-9]|1[0-2]"`? The mask can be approximate, like `[/[01]/, /\d/]`.

Comment: some input example?

Comment: @ZiTAL 01,11,12,09 - inotherwords month numbers.

Comment: you showed me the path.would you like to put it as an answer? This works: `[/[01]/, /[0-2]/]` @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in the array imposes restriction on what char a user can input. It seems they are context-unaware. `[/0[1-9]/, /1[0-2]/]` means the first symbol can consist of `0` and a digit from `1` to `9` and the second symbol should start with `1` and then be followed with `0`, `1` or `2` - which is always false.

You may thus use an *approximate* mask like

```
this.mask = [/[01]/, /\d/];
```

The first placeholder will be valid if `0` or `1` is typed, and the second placeholder will be valid for any digit.

And to make sure the month values are typed, I suggest adding `pattern="0[1-9]|1[0-2]"` for the on-submit validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation :)

Comment: one small issue is there.do you know how to avoid this? `00`.now it is possible.

Comment: Yes, just what I wrote: it is not possible to write a context-aware pattern with this library. You should use a workaround, I suggest adding `pattern="0[1-9]|1[0-2]"` for the on-submit validation.

Comment: you mean I need to use both.For mask this `[/[01]/, /[0-2]/]` and normal regex validation like this `/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/`.As a second rule.Am I right?

Comment: Not a rule, as an HTML5 `pattern` attribute. `<input type="text" pattern="regex"/>`

Comment: got it.I was wrong.your oldest comment on my question is the correct one. please change your answer for it.this should be the mask then `[/[01]/, /\d/]`.

Comment: Yep,`approximate mask` perfectly fit here.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Each element in the mask array restrict on what character a user can input. For example, `mark =  [/[1-9]/, /\d/]` means the user can enter only a number between 1 and 9 in the first placeholder, and only a digit in the placeholders after that.

In your case, each element of your mark `(/0[1-9]/, /1[0-2]/)` defined an valid pattern for entire input string, not for each character. That why it didn't work.

According to [text-mask angular2 document](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#mask), you can also pass a function as the mask. You should try something like this

```
this.mask = function(rawValue) {
        // add logic to generate your mask array  
        if (rawValue && rawValue.length > 0) {
            if (rawValue[0] == '0') {
                return [/[01]/, /[1-9]/];
            } else {
                return [/[01]/, /[0-2]/];
            }
        }
        return [/[01]/, /[0-9]/];
   }
```

Comment: it gives this compile time error: `[ts]
Type '(rawValue: any) => (string | RegExp)[]' is not assignable to type '(string | RegExp)[]'.
  Property 'push' is missing in type '(rawValue: any) => (string | RegExp)[]'.`

Comment: Have you tried to change line *mask: Array<string | RegExp>* to *mask:any*?

Comment: yes, now that error has gone.but it's having weird behavior.when I type `1` for the first character it automatically shows `01`.when I press `1` again it changes to `10`.do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, I think the logic inside function have to modify to archive your desired result, but now I've not figured it out.

Comment: I've updated the answer. if there is any problem, please feedback.

Comment: now I can enter like this: `13,14,15`.....? maximum value should be `12`.

Comment: Please update  condition to *if (rawValue && rawValue.length > 0)*